# check if int in list of specified enum values using Arrays.asList

Tags: java, list, enums, boxing

I was told to not do the below code and check using `&&` condition to make sure the resultCode is not one of the following. But I don't understand why this is won't work. It seems like it should. HttpStatus returns an int. The `resp.getResultCode()` returns a `Long`.

```
if(!Arrays.asList(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value(), HttpStatus.GONE.value(), HttpStatus.OK.value())
          .contains(resp.getResultCode())){
    // Do things
}
```

Whats wrong with the above?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, `getResultCode` returns a `Long`. And `HttpStatus.value()` returns an `int`, which is auto-boxed to a `java.lang.Integer` when you put it in a `List`.

And a `java.lang.Integer` is never equals to a `java.lang.Long`, so your if-statement always returns `false`.

That's apart from the efficiency reasons mentioned by @RichardSchwartz - not working at all trumps efficiency I suppose.

To make it work at all, you should:

1. If getResultCode returns a `long` (lower-case), you should cast it to an `int` first: `.contains((int)resp.getResultCode()))`
2. If it returns a `Long`, you should convert it to an `int` this way: `.contains(resp.getResultCode().intValue()))`

Here is the source code of `java.lang.Integer.equals`:

```
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj instanceof Integer) {
                return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend casting the long to int though. That seems really sketchy. I would probably create a vararg utility method like `static List<Long> toList(int... values);`.

Comment: @Radiodef [HTTP response codes range from 100 to 599](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml). No idea why a library would encode that with a `Long` but it's safe to cast a number in that range to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've coded it, the JVM will have to allocate memory to instantiate an Array object and then populate three elements. And then it will have to evaluate the contains method, which is going to iterate through the Array elements. The memory for the Array object will (eventually) have to be garbage collected. This will make your code run less efficiently than the straightforward approach.

Also, nobody else is going to be able to just glance at your code and immediately know exactly what it means.

Comment: The thing I'm really getting at is the condition. Will it work as I'm expecting it to? Or is there a bug in the code?

Comment: I don't know if there's a bug in your code. I'm just telling you some good reasons why you should listen to whomever is telling you not to do it that way. If you want to ignore that advice and write code that is slower and more difficult to understand, then by all means go ahead and test it to find out for yourself if there's a bug.

Comment: +1 for "go ahead and test it to find out for yourself if there's a bug". Programmer have to test his code instead of posting it into a forum for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a performance issue in your code. You are creating list object unnecessarily. Java object creation is the most expensive operation you could perform. So, I can say use "&&" or "switch case" and avoid creating objects in possible cases.